# Quicktime Automator + Applescript for QuickTime reference files

Tags: applescript, automator, quicktime

I'm trying to create an Automator droplet that allows me to pass one or more video files to an Applescript that then saves out reference files with "_ref.mov" appended to the file name by using QuickTime Player 7.

Saving as a reference is the default save method, which is why I'm not using `save reference file` function (also, because I can't find any docs on the `using descriptors` attribute object.)

I found this script on another forum, and it works, but it doesn't accomplish exactly what I need because it requires that 1) a file is open and 2) the user manually specifies an output file name.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
        activate
        try
            if not (exists document 1) then display dialog "please open a quicktime movie." buttons {"cancel"} default button 1 with icon 1
            set theFile to (choose file name)
            save document 1 in theFile
            close document 1
        end try
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

I've tried to make changes to accomplish what I need, but my changes break the script:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
        activate
        try
            open input
            set theFile to ((path of input) & "_ref.mov))
            save document 1 in theFile
            close document 1
        end try
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

I've also tried:

`set theFile to (((path of input) & "_ref.mov") as text)` doesn't work

either does `as alias` or `as string`

Not sure where I'm going wrong. Please help if you can!

Comment: What does "break the script" mean?

Comment: By "break the script" I mean it no longer creates an output as expected. The script in its original from produces a file. After I make my adjustments, the script no longer produces any output.

Comment: Does `open input` actually open what you want it to? If it does and that's not the problem, try coercing (casting) `theFile` to a `file` object with `as file`, or by sticking the word `file` right after `to` in your assignment statement (this uses the string as a name specifier). See the AppleScript language guide for reference on what all these types actually mean; it's like day and night once you've read up on this stuff thoroughly and scrutinously (I know that fact from cold, hard experience). Otherwise, I'm not sure what's going wrong here, sorry.